# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException in my JApplet

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, nullpointerexception, japplet

I'm having a huge problem trying to fix this piece of code, I keep getting a massive error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.allcare.arfile.CloudStoreInfo.getStoreInfoFromProvider(CloudStoreInfo.java:62)
at com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet.listBlobStoreContents(ArFileJApplet.java:959)
at com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet.uploadFile(ArFileJApplet.java:938)
at com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet.sendCloud_buttonActionPerformed(ArFileJApplet.java:807)
at com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet.access$1400(ArFileJApplet.java:26)
at com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet$14.actionPerformed(ArFileJApplet.java:445)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I think the problem is with my assignment. I know for a fact that there is at the very least 1 full parts variable from the list I'm getting. I've tried printing out each element of the elements variable and they are all in there (but I must do this before I begin assignment else it doesn't get to the function), but it simply never makes it to my print statement (it's also not the cause, I've tried commenting it out). I just cannot find what exactly is null:

```
public void getStoreInfoFromProvider(BlobStore blobStore)
{
    ListContainerOptions listOptions = new ListContainerOptions();
    String temp = blobStore.list("", listOptions.recursive()).toString(); // returns a string containing all info of the filesystem on the cloud

    // remove the [ and ] characters as well as split whenever encounters [t
    temp = temp.replaceFirst("\\[\\[", "");
    temp = temp.replaceFirst("\\]\\]", "");
    String[] parts = temp.split("\\[t"); 

    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        String[] elements = parts[x].split(", ");

        System.out.println(elements.length);
        System.out.println(elements[x]);

// this line below is where the code breaks, if i comment it out, then the next line breaks and so on and so forth
        type[x] = elements[0];
        providerId[x] = elements[1];
        name[x] = elements[2];
        location[x] = elements[3];
        scope[x] = elements[4];
        description[x] = elements[5];
        parent[x] = elements[6];
        isoCodes[x] = elements[7];
        metadata[x] = elements[8];
        uri[x] = elements[9];
        userMetadata[x] = elements[10];

        printSingleCloudStoreInfo(x);
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `NullPointerException at ..(CloudStoreInfo.java:62)` Which is line 62?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard about the simplified for-loop? Well, there is a reason to call it simplified...

```
public void getStoreInfoFromProvider (BlobStore blobStore)
{
    ListContainerOptions listOptions = new ListContainerOptions ();
    // returns a string containing all info of the filesystem on the cloud
    String temp = blobStore.list ("", listOptions.recursive ()).toString (); 

    temp = temp.replaceFirst("\\[\\[", "");
    temp = temp.replaceFirst("\\]\\]", "");
    String[] parts = temp.split("\\[t"); 

    for (String part: parts) 
    {
        String[] elements = part.split(", ");
        System.out.println(elements.length);
        // ...
```

I'm just guessing, where line 62 is. You should mark it with a comment or describe it somehow, by citing it.

#### update:

Since line 62 is marked now:

If type is set to null, it isn't initialized, but null. You have to initialize it with the size you need - for example, as it is a String array: String [] type = new String[2];. If you don't initialize it, you don't have room reserved to store type [0];

Comment: the reason im not using the simplified for loop is because i simply want to get the code working for a single case. Once i get one working then ill move to using a proper for loop. I think i might test using a List of strings next to see if that rectifies the issue, still any help in understanding whats going wrong here would be great

Comment: ok just implemented using list and well it worked immediately.... *face palm* if you can figure out why this occurred so that it never happens again it would be much appreciated, however at this stage i think ill be sticking with lists from now on

Comment: @MatthewPigram: Where do you use List now? So, from your marked line, throwing the error - what do the two lines above print? Length is > 0? So  type, the array is null. Initializing an array and initializing it's elements are two different things. I bet type is null. Try a `if (type == null) System.err.println ("type is null");` before your comment.

Comment: i was printing the length of parts to see if it was getting a correct value and stuff was actually getting put in it. type is initialised as null, however i am setting it to elements[0] in the loop, perhaps the error occured because I initialised the whole string array to null rather that individually to each element in the array

Comment: If type is set to null, it isn't initialized, but null. You have to initialize it with the size you need - for example, as it is a String array: `String [] type = new String[2];`. If you don't initialize it, you don't have room reserved to store type [0];